# Do Chrome and Firefox give you a certificate error for a locally signed certificate even if the certificate is in the trusted store?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I created a self signed certificate for local testing. The certificate generates an error in firefox and chrome saying:

```
myPC:443 uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.

(Error code: sec_error_ca_cert_invalid)
```

The certificate is self signed, but it's also in my trusted certificate store.

As a result, I would expect firefox and chrome to trust it because by adding it to my trusted certificate store I have declared it's legitimate.

However, they don't, and I am not sure if this is standard behaviour (that the browsers ignore the trusted store) or if it is a genuine configuration problem with my certificate.

It is ok in Internet Explorer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the self-signing "CA"'s certificate to Firefox's and Chrome's certificate, or just the self-signed cert itself? `sec_error_ca_cert_invalid` implies that the browser is trying to follow the certificate chain up to the CA cert and failing; if you create a self-signing "CA" (as e.g. [here](http://www.freebsdmadeeasy.com/tutorials/freebsd/create-a-ca-with-openssl.php)), and then import its root certificate into Firefox and Chrome, they should be able to match the self-signed cert up with its root "CA" cert, and you should no longer have the issue.